# String.prototype does not implement all ES6 spec Symbols as Keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Reading the Symbol spec from here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) I saw that `String.prototype` should contain this list of keys:

```
Symbol.match,

Symbol.replace,

Symbol.search,
```

... and others

But when I tested this in Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m it turned out that `String.prototype` contains only `Symbol.iterator` as a key.

[image] So what I have not understood correctly, is String.prototype suppose to contain this Symbol keys or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of the things listed in [§6.1.5.1 - Well-Known Symbols](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-well-known-symbols).

It's not that `String.prototype` is supposed to contain `@@match` (for instance) as a key, it's that `@@match` is a well-known symbol *used* by the implementation of the function assigned to `String.prototype.match`. The key for that function on `String.prototype` is a string, `"match"`, not a symbol.

Comment: Humm OK but isn't the point of having this well-known Symbols (@@iterator, @@match ... and others) exactly to be used as keys for object properties and methods ? At least this is how @@iterator is used. How @@match could be used inside String.prototype.match ?

Comment: @Hivaga: Sort of. As it says in the first paragraph of the link above: *"Well-known symbols are built-in Symbol values that are explicitly referenced by algorithms of this specification. They are typically used as **the keys of properties whose values serve as extension points of a specification algorithm**."* (my emphasis) `@@match` *is* used as a key elsewhere, in `RegExp.prototype` for instance. Essentially providing a well-known symbol for `@@match` lets you define any object as being able to do a regular expression match; it's what's checked by the abstract `IsRegExp`, for instance.

Comment: (Sorry, the emphasis looks like shouting. Isn't meant that way.)